# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in View Blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I have a problem that's made me confused for almost 4 hours hahaha,
The detail is on this link https://flareapp.io/share/dmkYlXy7#F50

In my hosting, it looks to have an error, but in my local, it's fine. I don't really understand this situation.

I attach my controller code:

```
    public function readBlog($slug, Request $request)
    {
        // Update job count views
        $blogView = blog::where('slug', $slug)->with('user', 'image', 'file', 'categories', 'subcategories')->first();
        $blogView->views += 1;
        $blogView->save();

        $blogGet = blog::where('userid', $blogView->user->id)->orderBy('views', 'DESC')->with('image')->limit(3)->get();
        return view('home.read-blog', ['blogs' => $blogView, 'blogArr' => $blogGet]);
        // return response()->json($blogView);
    }
```

and this is my view blade code

```
@extends('welcome')
@section('title', $blogs->seo_title ?? $blogs->title)
@section('page_description', $blogs->seo_description)
@section('page_keywords', 'blog boxity, boxity, boxityerp, realizeboxity, boxity central
indonesia, erp boxity, warehouse management, human resources management, financial management, boxity warehouse, boxity
WMS, boxity financial, boxity indonesia, news from boxity')
@section('tag_cover',$blogs->image->file)
@section('content')
<section id="single-post" class="wide-100 inner-page-hero single-post-section division">
    <div class="container">
       blablabla
    </div>
</section>
```

Please help me. I have already attached my [flareapp link](https://flareapp.io/share/dmkYlXy7#F50) too.

Thanks mate!

Comment: `blog::where(...` needs to be `Blog::where(...` On your server, casing is important, locally it is not in some cases. Make sure the filenames, classnames and namespace are correct too.

Comment: Agree with @GertB. need to be careful about naming conventions and casing

Comment: Thank you for the response, sir. @GertB.
But I have already checked it, and I can be sure that the model's name is right, sir.
`
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


class blog extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'blogs';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'category',
        'views',
        'userid', 'status', 'slug', 'seo_title', 'seo_description', 'subcategory'
    ];
}
`

Comment: @GertB. Sir, this is my attached link to the screenshot image, sir. https://imgur.com/a/v92ksV0 Please have a look, sir. Thank you, sir.

Comment: @bintangjtobing `class blog` needs to be `class Blog` and the filename needs to be  `Blog.php` If you want Laravel to load the files correctly, you need to use the naming conventions

Comment: I've already changed the name, but it makes an error like this, https://flareapp.io/share/17WlLj35 I've also already `php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan optimize:clear` and it's no reaction. What'd I miss, sir?

Comment: Are you sure it's in `App` or in `App\Models` (as it should be)?

Comment: Yes.. I can be sure, sir. You can see my attached screenshot, sir. https://imgur.com/a/CidrwVC 

And this is the response when I have already changed the model's name, sir.
https://imgur.com/u6Tnwgk

this is my URL, sir. https://boxity.id/blog/read/erp-software-the-good-and-the-bad-what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-erp-software

Comment: This is an issue with php version difference, you should check the version on your server and make changes accordingly on your loclhost or if you've access to update or downgrade php version you should do it on your server according to your local environment, make sure php version should be same on both server and localhost. most of the time this issue caused by php version 7.4

Comment: try to run ```composer dump-autoload``` to autoload all the files, also you should place your model files inside Model directory as suggested by  
@geertjanknapen

Comment: I've done with `composer dump-autoload`, and it's still like that. hehe I have no idea again, sir. To confused.